# ForeignKey Referencing Same Table

Tags: mysql, sql

There was an interview test in which below was the table and structure

```
 Table Person = id, name, dob, dod, mother_id, father_id
 Primary Key (id)
 Foreign Key mother_id references Person
 Foreign Key father_id references Person
```

and it was asked

> 1. "select all who are mothers"
> 2. "select those child who are children of 'John Smith' and 'Jane'

and I was puzzled because I was assuming that foreign key would be linked with some other table as usual. But at that point I failed. do some one know the actual answer and reason?

Comment: Have you done [some research](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) before asking here?

Comment: Why would you assume the key would reference another table?  Is a `Mother` and a `Father` not just a `Person`?

Comment: For the record, this is called a self join. This is very common (i.e. a well known feature in SQL) so you should be able to find a lot on the subject by searching for "SQL self join" in Google.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This kind of data structure is called a "Self Referencing Table"

```
SELECT DISTINCT mothers.*
FROM person
    inner join person mothers on person.mother_id = mothers.id
```

and

```
SELECT person.*
FROM person
    inner join person fathers on person.father_id = fathers.id
    inner join person mothers on person.mother_id = mothers.id
WHERE 
    fathers.name='john smith'
and 
    mothers.name='jane'
```

Comment: but where are you selecting fathers.name and mothers.name? as we don't have that column, could you please explain?

Comment: the person table has the name in it. I have aliased it as mothers and fathers in the join.

Answer (score 2):

You can always have foreign key that link to the same table.. There is not problem in that..

See, suppose you are storing a person record in the table, now that person would be having mother and father. And `mother` and `father` both are themselves a person.. so, they are itself a record of the same table..

**Suppose you have following two records in Person table: -**

```
id     name           age         mother_id
1      xyz            24          5
5      abc            57          6
```

So, from the above table you see that, `person` with `id = 5` is actually mother of person with `id = 1`.. So, it is a `foreign key` referencing the same table..

So, here rather than performing a `join` operation with a different table, you have to perform join with the same table..

```
SELECT p2.id FROM
Person p1 join Person p2
WHERE p1.mother_id = p2.id
```

This query will select the record of `mother` of your current record..

Answer (score 2):

> I was assuming that foreign key would be linked with some other table
>   as usual.

It still is - it references other records in the same Person table.

```
-- All Mothers
SELECT mom.name
   FROM Person mom
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Person WHERE mother_id = mom.id);

-- Children of John Smith and Jane
SELECT kid.name
   FROM Person kid
   INNER JOIN Person mom on kid.mother_id = mom.id
   INNER JOIN Person dad on kid.father_id = dad.id
   WHERE mom.name = 'Jane' AND
   dad.name = 'John Smith';
```

Have a look at this [SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/623f6/7) here

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Person 
WHERE father_id = (SELECT id FROM Person WHERE name = 'John Smith')
AND    mother_id = (SELECT id FROM Person WHERE name = 'Jane')
```

Comment: Corrected, was thinking was asking for either parent not both while typing my answer

Answer (score 1):

The answer was already given by podiluska, just explaining how it works since it looks like you're new to MySql.

By giving an Alias to a table(like mother or father to the table person) you do something like a pseudo-table, that the MySql interprets as another table, so the join happens normally, just imagine there are 3 tables now. Person, Father and Mother, and they are all linked together by the join.